# C++ error: "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I have to build a C++ library for Windows in a Linux environment, using g++. I get this error when I build it:

```
RWGVector.cpp:5: error: g++ error: "expected constructor, destructor, 
or type conversion before '<' token
```

Building it in Visual Studio 2010 does not return any error.  I am building this using the C++11 (aka c++0x) standard.

I have two files, one with the template class declaration (RWGVector.h), the other one with the constructor (RWGVector.cpp).  I only kept the essential parts of each file, responsible for the error.

RWGVector.h:

```
#ifndef _RWGVECTOR_H
#define _RWGVECTOR_H

#include <vector>
#include <rw/generic.h>

template<typename V> class RWGVector
{
    public:
        RWGVector<V>();

    private:
        std::vector<V> vector_;
};
#endif
```

RWGVector.cpp:

```
#include "RWGVector.h"

template<typename V>
RWGVector<V>::RWGVector() : vector_()       //<--- Line 5
{
}
```

What causes this error?  How do I fix it?

**Solution:**

Remove the `<V>` in `RWGVector<V>();` as

> *In class the constructor need not the claim of template parameter.Because when you specify the class, the parameter has been conformed*

Though I had an other issue, more specific to my situation, because of the < rw/generic.h > file included, which contains the following line:

```
#define RWGVector(Type) RWTValVector<Type>
```

Commenting that line solved the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#ifndef _RWGVECTOR_H
#define _RWGVECTOR_H

#include <vector>
#include <rw/generic.h>

template<typename V> class RWGVector
{
    public:
        RWGVector(); //  RWGVector<V> is wrong;

    private:
        std::vector<V> vector_;
};
#endif
```

In `class` the constructor need not the claim of template parameter.Because when you specify the `class`, the parameter has been conformed

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I dropped the <V> and got an other error:
`RWGVector.h:10: error: expected ';' before '<' token`

Found the cause though, will edit my post with the solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `<V>` in `RWGVector<V>();` in `RWGVector.h`.

Comment: Dropped it and got an other error:
`RWGVector.h:10: error: expected ';' before '<' token`

Found the cause though, will edit my post with the solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `<V>` here.

Just do in your `RWGVector.h`:

```
template<typename V> class RWGVector
{
public:
    RWGVector();
    //      ^^^

// ...
};
```

Comment: Dropped the <V> and got an other error:
`RWGVector.h:10: error: expected ';' before '<' token`

Found the cause though, will edit my post with the solution :) Thanks!